# sympy diff without resubstituting?

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math

I'm facing problems using python sympy.

The problem is reduced to very minimal working examples

```py
import sympy as sp
from sympy import *

x, xb, xi, alpha = sp.symbols('x xbar xi alpha')
Eqxb = sp.Eq(xb, (x+xi) )
problemExpr = (xb*cos(alpha))**2

# Following is zero for sure
display( problemExpr.diff(xi) )

# Naive approach
out = problemExpr.subs(xb, Eqxb.rhs).diff(xi).subs(Eqxb.rhs, xb)
display( out ) # gives (2x + 2 xi)*cos^2(alpha)
# Want I want is 2*xb*cos^(alpha)

# Some simple tests
test1 = (Eqxb.rhs + xb) 
display(test1.subs(Eqxb.rhs, xb)) # gives 2*xbar | -> good

# 
test2 = 2*(Eqxb.rhs + xb) 
display(test2.subs(Eqxb.rhs, xb)) # gives 2*x + 2*xbar + 2*xi | -> not good

# 
test3 = 2*x + 2*xi
display(test3.subs(Eqxb.rhs, xb)) # gives 2*x + 2*xi | -> not good

# test 4, explicit version 
display(test3.subs( { x+xi : xb })) # gives 2*x + 2*xi | -> not good
```

Questions 1:
Why is the expression `x+xi` not properly substituted with `xb`. Am I using this function wrong? At least in `test1` it works as expected.

Question 2:
Here, this is a simple function with only one substitution. How is this performed, if multiple subs are necessary? This step of subs and re-subs seems like there should be at least one more elegant way.

Comment: Use `rep = solve(Eqxb, x, dict=True)` and then `expr.subs(rep)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about keeping a dictionary of things that you want to be able to differentiate but also want to represent as a simpler expression (like `xb`). Use a function of `xb` to do this as follows:

```py
import sympy as sp
from sympy import *

x, xi, alpha = sp.symbols('x xi alpha')
xb = Function('xb')(x)
f = {xb: (x+xi)}
d = {k.diff(x):v.diff(x) for k,v in f.items()}
eq = (xb*cos(alpha))**2
>>> eq.diff(x)
2*xb(x)*cos(alpha)**2*Derivative(xb(x), x)
>>> eq.diff(x).subs(d)
2*xb(x)*cos(alpha)**2
>>> eq.diff(x).subs(d).subs(f)
2*(x + xi)*cos(alpha)**2
```

The issue of trying to replace a sum with a symbol is an often asked question. Unless the sum appears exactly as given in subs -- not with a constant multiplying each term -- the substitution will fail. Solving for one of the symbols in the sum other than the one you want to have in the final expression is the usual solution, e.g.

```py
>>> from sympy.abc import y
>>> rep= solve(Eq(x + xi, y),exclude=[y],dict=True)[0]
>>> (2*x + 2*xi).subs(rep)
2*y
```

Comment: Thank you! Using a dict seems to be a good workaround. With `exclude` this is very handy.